# Error:Execution failed for task 'app:generateDebugBuildConfig'

Tags: android, gradle

Error:Execution failed for task 'app:generateDebugBuildConfig'

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\bok\Desktop\Zipzap\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\storie\myapp \BuildConfig.java (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)

What's the solution ..

I hope to find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 13):

Try to clean project this is working for me

for android

```
$ cd android 

$ ./gradlew clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` getting this when using `./gradelew clean` in my terminal

Comment: use `Ctrl` + `Enter` to run command from Android Studio terminal

Answer (score 2):

Changing port worked for me

You Could try:

`react-native run-android --port=8082`

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean and rebuild project or you can try to remove whole build folder and build after removing. If it won't help, show your build.gradle, your current information isn't enough to recognise the reason of problem.

Answer (score 1):

**React Native**

Faced similar issue while building react native app. Running on the different port as the default port (8081) is used by some other app.

Command to build the app.

`react-native run-android --port=8082`

**Solution**

Removed extra attribute `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. If you check the log, it says

> lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 56; Attribute "screenOrientation" bound
>   to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already
>   specified for element "activity".

hence removed the same attribute. This was being added multiple times

**Error log**

```
Configure project :react-native-webview
:react-native-webview:reactNativeAndroidRoot /Users/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/react-native/android

Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/PROJECT_PATH/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 56; Attribute "screenOrientation" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "activity".

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
32 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 31 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
```

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to project root.
2. Go to android folder.
   `cd android`
3. Clean gradle.
   `.\gradlew clean`
   (`./gradlew clean` didnot work for me for some reason.)
4. Go back to root.
   `cd ..`
5. Run react native.
   `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

In android studio,

1. On the Menu Bar, go to `build`
2. Click `clean project` and wait for project to clean
3. Then on the menu bar again, go to `build` -> `rebuild project` and wait for project to rebuild.
4. That's all